# How to use my own view in an Android layout?

Tags: android

I have created one view, view code is,

```
   public class MyDraw extends View{

    

    //List<Point> mArryLstpoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Paint paint =new Paint();
    Paint mPaintAlphabet = new Paint();
    public MyDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        
    
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         
    
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public MyDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
             
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        
        mPaintAlphabet.setDither(true);
        mPaintAlphabet.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaintAlphabet.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaintAlphabet.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaintAlphabet.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaintAlphabet.setStrokeWidth(3);
        mPaintAlphabet.setTextSize(400);
    }
    
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawText("A",100,350, mPaintAlphabet);
        System.out.println("in on draw");
        for(Point mPoint:MyAlphabetsActivity.mArryLstpoints)
        canvas.drawCircle(mPoint.x, mPoint.y, 12, paint);
        
    }
    
    }
```

I want use this view in layout and I want to set background images for the view. I am using following code,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <com.qteq.myalphabets.MyDraw
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" ></com.qteq.myalphabets.MyDraw>
```

My activity class is,

```
public class MyAlphabetsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    MyDraw mMyDraw;
    Button mBtnOk;
    AttributeSet attributeSet;
    public static List<Point> mArryLstpoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*
         * getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
         * WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         */
        /*
         * mMyDraw=new MyDraw(this); setContentView(mMyDraw);
         * mMyDraw.requestFocus();
         */
        mMyDraw = (MyDraw) findViewById(R.id.mMyDraw_layout);
        mMyDraw.bringToFront();
        mMyDraw.requestFocus();
        mMyDraw.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Point mPoint=new Point();
                mPoint.x=event.getX();
                mPoint.y=event.getY();
                System.out.println("in on touch");
                mArryLstpoints.add(mPoint);
                System.out.println("Array list is-----"+mArryLstpoints);
                
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                return true;
            }
        });
        // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
    class Point{
        public float srtx;
        float x, y;
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            System.out.println("in on point");
            return x + ", " + y;       
    }
    }
```

and Displaying and onTouch Method called only one time.

Comment: After adding setContentView(R.layout.main) in onTouch method,it is working up to one time only,next not working...

Comment: You didn't post your full code so its difficult to tell.Post your full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Adding view with fill_parent width and height , so no space to add other views like buttons and images .

one of the possible implementation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <com.qteq.myalphabets.MyDraw
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_contentt" ></com.qteq.myalphabets.MyDraw>
<Button/>
<ImageView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dont forget to add constructor

```
public MyDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, ttributeSet);
```

in MyDraw.java

************ **editing** **************

in `onTouch()`
return `super(v, event)` instead of `true` ;
also check if you need to write `setOnTouchListener()` to view or canvas .

Comment: Hi Rajawat thanks for reply, i have include the above code to my app....it is displaying view...but view is not working....means my view contains alphabet "A" ,if we draw any where like "A" or "B" or "C" this not working

Comment: might be ordinates 150,450 out of canvas boundary . so first get Height and width bt Canvas.getHeight() .. and draw alhabet within its boundary . one more possibility is on of ur circle in second loop overlapping with alphabet .

Comment: alphabet is displaying(very small)...but drawing is not working....means onTouch method is not calling

Comment: i made changes in my code please check and please give suggestions for solve this problem...please

Answer (score 1):

You can place your view within a layout in your XML and there can be other elements, as well, within that layout. You can set layout background to something, too.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="@drawable/mybackground">

 <com.qteq.myalphabets.MyDraw
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for replay..i have used the code in my layout.it's giving Layout InflateException

Comment: Might be because I've spelled wrap-content instead of wrap_content. I've corrected. Why do you want to inflate can you probably just use setContentView in your Activity

Comment: public class MyActivity extends Activity {


 MyDraw mMyDraw;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
}